# Modify display tag in wec:outputHtml

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, facelets

I have to modify the presentation of the following tag on a Facelets page:

```
<wec:outputHtml id="ohOv" value="#{cc.vch.itemOverview}" />
```

Current output on screen:

> ID: 0.1875" OD: 0.25" Length: 0.25" *Material Details*

Desired output on screen:

> ID: 0.1875" 
>   OD: 0.25" 
>   Length: 0.25" 
>   *Material Details*

In other words, I want to preserve newlines. Note that *Material Details* is a link.

I tried the following:

1. Using CSS `white-space:pre-line;` on `<wec:outputHtml styleClass>`
2. Using JavaScript:

   ```
   var myVar = "#{cc.vch.itemOverview}".text;
   document.write(myVar);
   ```

   I am not able to display any javascript variable while assigning it the value.

Comment: How exactly does `white-space:pre-line` fail? It should work, unless you're *actually* not printing `\n` characters (you should be seeing those linebreaks in the generated HTML output which you can see by rightclick, *View Source* in browser). Does your browser support that property value? Have you tried `white-space:pre` instead?

Comment: Yes it working correctly i have use <h:outputText> tag with the respective style class (white-space:pre-line) and had added an attribute : escape="false"